# Sifr 3 Links Problem

Tags: sifr

I am currently coding a site that is using an extensive amount of sifr'ed links.  The appearance of the sifr'ed text is fine, however the links only seem to work in Safari.  I have seen that there are several other people having trouble with firefox with older versions of sifr, however I have updated to the latest nightly build for Sifr3.

The site is www.lauravinchesi.com/final/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to not replace the `<a>` directly, but replace its parent element.